# Differences between Ubuntu Software Center and Ubuntu Software & their pros and cons

Tags: software-center, gnome-software

1. What are the technical differences between "Ubuntu Software Center" and "Ubuntu Software"?
2. How to use them effectively or when to use what?
3. Is there any pros & cons for them? If yes, then what are they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only there is a difference between  GNOME Software Centre (`gnome-software`) and Ubuntu Software Centre (`software-centre`)

Of which GNOME Software Centre is created by the gnome project where they added support for Snaps to GNOME Software Centre instead of Ubuntu Software Centre

Meanwhile Ubuntu Software Centre (`software-centre`) is created by Canonicals as a user-friendly way to discover and install apt packages (friendlier than Synaptic, which was the package manager at the time).

Where as the latest Ubuntu release is shipped with `gnome-software` by default.

Answer (score 13):

> "What are the technical differences between "Ubuntu Software Center"
>   and "Ubuntu Software"?"

Functionally, they are, more or less, the same, both pull software from your repository’s and install it.

`ubuntu-software-center` was developed years ago for Ubuntu and is considered slow and dated.

`ubuntu-software` is actually the `gnome-software` app and is a more modern software app.

> "Is there any pros & cons for them? If yes, then what are they?"

`ubuntu-software-center` is slower, older and replaced by `gnome-sofware` even by Canonical in the main Ubuntu release, that is it for objective pros and cons as far as I know.

> "How to use them effectively or when to use what?"

Simply use the one you like best, they do the same thing, like I said `ubuntu-software-center` is older, no longer in development but if you prefer that one, it works just fine.

Of course, the UI is different but a better UI is very subjective, I can't tell you what you would like best, Gnome is a lot more minimal and the software centre could be considered "cluttered" by some.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that Software center has more utilities than the newer Ubuntu Software. I was looking for some dvd rip programs and the old Software center has more.